# SonarQube not able to read jasmine test report generated using karma-junit-reporter

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sonarqube, karma-runner

I used `karma-junit-reporter` to generate jasmine test case report `TESTS-xunit.xml` which is in the following format :

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)" package="" timestamp="2016-01-01T11:36:54" id="0" hostname="VANIGU03" tests="107" errors="0" failures="0" time="85.676">
    <properties>
      <property name="browser.fullName" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34"/>
    </properties>
    <testcase name="model definition should exist" time="0.001" classname="PhantomJS_198_(Windows_7_000).Check SimpleViewModel load process"/>
    <testcase name="model instance should be successfully created" time="0" classname="PhantomJS_198_(Windows_7_000).Check SimpleViewModel load process"/>
    <testcase name="result should be equal to 1" time="0" classname="PhantomJS_198_(Windows_7_000).Simple test"/>
    <testcase name="ImplCustomerAccountsModel should be defined" time="2.204" classname="PhantomJS_198_(Windows_7_000).ImplCustomerAccountsModel test suite"/>
```

But when I am running sonar...I am getting following exception:

```
[WARN] [15:58:06.102] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplInvoiceListViewModel Test,  _ascDate method", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplInvoiceListViewModel Test,  _ascDate method.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.118] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).implVasViewModel Test,  _customSortings array time object asc method", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\implVasViewModel Test,  _customSortings array time object asc method.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.133] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplInvoiceListViewModel Test,  _descDate method", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplInvoiceListViewModel Test,  _descDate method.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.148] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplCreditAndDebitNoteViewModel Test,  method _ascAmount", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplCreditAndDebitNoteViewModel Test,  method _ascAmount.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.162] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplCreditAndDebitNoteModel test suite", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplCreditAndDebitNoteModel test suite.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.177] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplCreditAndDebitNoteViewModel Test,  method getListAttachmentUrl", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplCreditAndDebitNoteViewModel Test,  method getListAttachmentUrl.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.193] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).implVasViewModel Test,  _customSortings array time object desc method", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\implVasViewModel Test,  _customSortings array time object desc method.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.207] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplCustomerSubscriptionsModel test suite", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplCustomerSubscriptionsModel test suite.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.220] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplInvoiceListModel test suite", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplInvoiceListModel test suite.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.234] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplCreateTicketWidget test suite", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplCreateTicketWidget test suite.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.249] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).implVasViewModel Test,  searchUsageVas method", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\implVasViewModel Test,  searchUsageVas method.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.262] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).Simple test", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\Simple test.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.277] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplCreditAndDebitNoteViewModel Test,  method _descAmount", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplCreditAndDebitNoteViewModel Test,  method _descAmount.js"
[WARN] [15:58:06.291] Test result will not be saved for test class "9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0).ImplCreateTicketViewModel test suite", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "9\8 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\ImplCreateTicketViewModel test suite.js"
```

Just wanted to understand what I am missing here?
Is there any issues in my TESTS-xunit.xml format? 
Why sonar not able to read it?

Comment: To get file name plugin takes everything after first dot in classname. FYI since 2.10 version of javascript plugin this feature is removed, please use the Generic Test Coverage (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) plugin to import test results